# Responsive design in bootstrap and html

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in .net and bootstrap. I am trying to design a web page.but when I see the page in smaller size ' whole of the structure became messy.I have some rows in each col-md-6 and I want to see a text after own image in row. but in small size text goes under image.
please look at source code in web page.
sorry for my bad  English.
you can see the page in this address . [][1]

[1]:

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row ">

        <div class="col-md-6  " id="" style="background-color: #ff6a00; min-height: 650px;">

            <div class="row" style="min-height: 35%">

                <img class="img-responsive img-logo" src="img/about-us.jpg" style="transform: rotate(-10deg);" />

            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #ff6a00;min-height:550px;top:300px;">
                <div class="direction" style="color: black;">
                     <h4 style="padding-right:50px;">درباره ما</h4>
                    <br />
                    <div class=" float pading-top text-justify text">

                            <p>
                               some text
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!----------------------------->

            <div class="col-md-6 otherbak2 " id="boss" >
                <div class="row height margin-top2 " >
                    <div class="col-md-6 height2 " >
                        <img class="img-responsive img-logo height2" src="img/png-ico/ali.JPG" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6  height float" >
                        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 17px; color: #d9534f">

                           some text
                             </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="row height margin-top2 ">

                    <div class="col-md-6 height2" >
                    <img class="img-responsive img-logo  height2" src="img/png-ico/mazdak.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6  height float" >
                        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 17px; color: #f0ad4e">
                             some text
                              </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row height margin-top2 ">
                    <div class="col-md-6 height2" >
                        <img class="img-responsive img-logo  height2" src="img/png-ico/babak.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 height  " >
                        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 17px;color: #ea4619">

                             some text
                            </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row height margin-top2 " >
                    <div class="col-md-6 height2">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-logo height2 " src="img/png-ico/amin.jpg" />
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6 height ">
                        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 17px;color:#24a947;">
                          some text
                            </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

   </div>
```

---

```
 <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url(../img/backgrnd.jpg);
    }

    .btn2 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #428bca;
        border-color: #428bca;
    }

    .width {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .height {
       min-height: 190px;
    }

    .height2 {
       min-height: 100%;
    }


    a:hover,
    a:focus {
        color: #FA6210;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .width {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .danger {
        color: #d9534f;
    }

    .warning {
        color: #f0ad4e;
    }

    .success {
        color: #5cb85c;
    }

    .info {
        color: #5bc0de;
    }

    .primary {
        color: #FA6210;
    }


    .btn2 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #428bca;
        border-color: #428bca;
    }


    .style {
        color: white;
    }

    .pading-top {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .margin-top {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .menu2 {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #096DB9;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    .menu3 {
        border-bottom: 8px solid #096DB9;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    }

    .direction {
        direction: rtl;
        float: right;
    }

    .direction2 {
        direction: ltr;
        float: left;
    }

    .float {
        float: right;
    }

    .padding {
        margin: 50px 5% 100px 5%;
    }

    .img-size {
        height: 128px;
        width: 128px;
    }

    .fixed2-menu {
        z-index: 1;
        direction: rtl;
        float: right;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .margin-top {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .margin-top2 {
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    .text {
        padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
        line-height: 25px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .opacity {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }


</style>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap design means you no need to wirte additional styles, already bootstrap is a full of css only. you can acheive what ever design you want. For reference use this Link:http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: First remove your addditional styles and do the design with bootstrap styles. for examples use this link:https://wrapbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chenge `height` to `min-height` in following line, it will prevent the picture goes behind the text

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0); min-height: 650px;" id="about" class="col-md-6  ">
```

---

good start but you can make it better in so many ways, problem is `height` and `height2` class. remove them and everything become fine. for picture you have another custom class named `img-logo` that one also make problem. instead of assigning `absolute` positioning to picture try `pull-left`

see below,i changed one of the block of codes

```
<div class="row height margin-top2 ">
     <div class="col-md-6 ">
           <img src="img/png-ico/ali.JPG" class="img-responsive pull-left">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6  ">
          <p style="font-size: 17px; color: #d9534f" class="text-center">
                رییس هیئت مدیره    
                        <br>
                علی کولیوند
           </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

p.s: sibil ghashangha ;)

Comment: I want to place "my text" be after Image but , it's placed under Image and I can't see part of the text. tnx for min-height . it workers for some problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest you do not need all the css you have created. 
Generally speaking the bootstrap styles can be grouped into 2 / 3 categories. (In my opinion at least)

- DOM infrastructure `[row, col-lg-12, etc..]`
- Component/element `[form-control, form-group, btn, etc..]`
- Style `[btn-primary btn-warning]`

You can for example change the style related parts, EG, button colours, font sizes (to an extent), swap out icon sets, and you'll be safe infrastructure wise.

What you must also take note of, is that you always need a max of 12 columns per row. EG

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-7'></div>
   <div class='col-md-5'></div>
</div>
```

In the sample you provided, it looks like some of your html tags might be miss-aligned. Which could be causing you some heart-ache. Id also get rid of some of those custom float classes.

**Your example**

```
 <div class="row height margin-top2 " >
   <div class="col-md-6 height2 " >
      <img class="img-responsive img-logo height2" src="img/png-ico/ali.JPG" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6  height float" >    
        some text                  
   </div>
 </div>
```

The problem here is that you're floating the right column right ... Which sounds weird. You don't need to.

If I understand the problem correctly you can possibly solve your issue with.

**CSS**

```
.text-padding {
   text-align: right;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-top: 80px; // half of your image size 190px
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row height margin-top2 " >
    <div class="col-md-6 height2 " >
        <img class="img-responsive img-logo height2" src="img/png-ico/ali.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 height text-padding" >    
         some text                  
    </div>
</div>
```